# login using django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

error looks something just like this KeyError: 'user'
while i try to login every time this error message is shown.I have installed the Django Rest Framework .What's the best way to do a login using Rest Framework?

my views

```
class LoginAPIView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = LoginSerializers(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user)
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({"status": status.HTTP_200_OK, "Token": token.key})
```

my serializers

```
class LoginSerializers(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User

        email = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
        password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        email = data.get('email', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)
        if email and password:

            user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
            if user:
                data['user'] = user

            data['user'] = user
        return data
```

Comment: why do you `return user` in `validate`?

Comment: That is my one mistake..after removing return user from validate i can only login one user which is superuser

Comment: Your validate method never raises a validation error, whereas it should if `user` is `None`. Apart from that, it should work. If you can only login for the superuser, maybe you should check how you create users.

Answer (score 5):

You are not raising ValidationError.
You need to refactor your seralizer and need to raise validation error if there is no user instance.

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from rest_framework import serializers

User = get_user_model()


class LoginSerializers(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = serializers.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        style={'input_type': 'password'},
        trim_whitespace=False,
        max_length=128,
        write_only=True
    )

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get('email')
        password = data.get('password')

        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(request=self.context.get('request'),
                                username=username, password=password)
            if not user:
                msg = _('Unable to log in with provided credentials.')
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')
        else:
            msg = _('Must include "username" and "password".')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')

        data['user'] = user
        return data
```

In LoginAPIView You should remove login(request,user) and instead use update_last_login(None,user).

```py
class LoginAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = LoginSerializers(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        update_last_login(None, user)
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({"status": status.HTTP_200_OK, "Token": token.key})
```

***If you want some thing simple just use built in Authentication provided by django-rest-framework***

```py
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                           context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
            'email': user.email
        })
```

You can find [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) for more detail

Comment: what is update_last_login?